# spark SQL thread blocked and running forever

Tags: apache-spark

When I run a Spark SQL application, it is running forever and not stopped.There is not data skew and high CPU occupancy. The following is the information that is located in the thread stack file

```
"SparkUI-54-acceptor-1@407beebf-Spark@361a6919{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4042}" #54 daemon prio=3 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007effdd622000 nid=0x2f8c9 runnable [0x00007efef6ce0000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
- locked <0x00000006c0405bd8> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:371)
at org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:601)
at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"SparkUI-53-acceptor-0@38dd8072-Spark@361a6919{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4042}" #53 daemon prio=3 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007effdd620800 nid=0x2f8c8 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007efef6de1000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:233)
- waiting to lock <0x00000006c0405bd8> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:371)
at org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:601)
at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.spark_project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue? We are also facing the same issue in spark 2.3. Please let me know if you are able to fix it